# Understanding syntax of generics in Java

Tags: java, hierarchy, class-hierarchy, generics

I started studying Java-generics. And I have some misunderstanding of the generics syntax and its meaning. I beg to treat with understanding if my question seems too trivial.

1. You can write:

   ```
   public class MyClass<SomeClass> {}
   ```
2. and you can write:

   ```
   public class MyClass<C extends SomeClass> {}
   ```
3. and you can write also:

   ```
   public class MyClass<? extends SomeClass> {}
   ```

What is the **difference between these cases**?

1. The first case is absolutely clear to me: you can use *instance of SomeClass* and *instance of his subclasses* as class's parameter for MyClass.
2. I think that in this case you can only use *instance of MyClass's subclasses*
3. The same: only use *instance of MyClass's subclasses* as class's parameter for MyClass.

Are my guesses right or not? And especially what is the difference between the using of the second and third cases?

Thanks in advance for explanation!

Comment: "3. and you can write also: public class MyClass<? extends SomeClass> {} " No you can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the difference is you cant use `?` in generic class declaration

```
public class MyClass<? extends SomeClass> {} // this isn't valid
```

The above declaration leads to compiler error.

[**From Documentation:**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

> A generic class is defined with the following format:
>
> class name { /* ... */ } The type parameter section,
>   delimited by angle brackets (<>), follows the class name. It specifies
>   the type parameters (also called type variables) T1, T2, ..., and Tn.

```
public class MyClass<C extends SomeClass> {}
```

In this declaration `C` is a **type-argument** which could be of type SomeClass or any of its SubClass's.

**Example :**

```
Class SomeOtherClass extends SomeClass {
}

MyClass clazz = new MyClass<SomeOtherClass>();
MyClass clazz = new MyClass<SomeClass>();
```